# Problems deploying MVC2 - Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.UrlParameter'

Tags: deployment, asp.net-mvc-2

I have problems deploying MVC2 application to my hosting. It shows the following error:

*Could not load type 'System.Web.Mvc.UrlParameter' from assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.*

It looks like it does not understand the new "optional URL parameters" feature of MVC2.
This is just a simple test application I created with "New Project" wizard in VWD 2008. It works ok localy both in IIS and Visual Studio web servers. MVC1 web sites are working ok on the hosting server. I've contacted the hosting support and they installed MVC2 but the problem still exists. The web site is working in ASP.NET 2.0 integrated pipeline mode.

Does anyone know why it is happening?

Comment: Have you managed to fix this yet? I've got the same issue and I'm convinced it's an old MVC version installed on my shared hosting package, however convincing my web hosting company of this is another matter. I'm curious to know whether any other circumstances can cause this problem to arise...

Comment: Yes, it's been fixed on my hosting once they installed .NET 4 with latest MVC2. If anyone has the same issue - try upgrading the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED:

Change id = UrlParameter.Optional to id = "" in Global.asax.

This change at least gets the site to render.

Answer (score 6):

What ya gotta do is copy the MVC dll locally. In visual studio's solution explorer do this:
Click the Show All Files button

[image]

The drop down the references section and select the System.Web.Mvc reference

[image: S]

Then in the properties window change Copy Local to true.

[image]

Comment: this resolve my issue of : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 2):

You should remove MVC2 RC then download and install MVC2 RC2.

Answer (score 1):

I also have this problem when deploying my MVC2 app to my hosts. Has anybody come up with a cause for this.

Changing the UrlParameter.Optional to a fixed value changes the behaviour of the app, so, I'm a little bit unhappy doing this.

Courtesy of Phil Haack (I'd love to take credit) but try bin deploying the System.Web.Mvc assembly by going to the properties of the reference to System.Web.Mvc and change Copy Local to true.

Dead impressed that Phil invested the time and energy to help on this.

Answer (score 0):

My application threw this exception when it couldn't find a dll file.

I use `Microsoft.Web.Mvc.AspNet4.dll` from ASP.NET MVC 2 Futures. I had the dll file on my workstation, but hadn't deployed it onto my web server.

Answer (score 0):

I got the error but I'm using MVC2 with .NET Framework 3.5 and that Class is targeted to .NET Framework 4.0.

I by mistake downloaded and assembly targeting .NET Framework 4.0 :(